# Cannot move out of borrowed content for Box::into_raw on self.attribute

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
pub struct Themepark {
    attraction: Box<Attraction>
}
```

**Note**: `Attraction` is a trait!

```
impl Themepark {

    pub fn open(&mut self) -> Result<(), ()> {

        let attraction = Box::into_raw(self.attraction);

    ...
    }

}
```

that gives me

```
> cannot move out of borrowed content
```

for `self.attraction` inside `Box::into_raw`

Now I do understand what that particular *error-message* means, but I don't understand how to solve it as `Box::into_raw` expects a `Box<T>` as argument, not a reference or anything.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  In most situations, you won't need a raw pointer to a trait object.  If you provide some more context you may get a better solution.

Comment: @SvenMarnach well, the actual problem is, that I'd like to get runtime-polymorphism like I am used to it in Java, Scala etc. Like, I don't know which attraction I get until Runtime. But I fear that's another question altogether.

Comment: @Sorona Trait objects actually do give you runtime polymorphism.  `Box<Attraction>` is a pointer to an instance of a type implementing the `Attraction` trait, but the actual type does not need to be known at compile time, so calling `self.attraction.visit()` will dynamically dispatch to the correct `visit()` implementation.  See also the [section on trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use that function on `self.attraction` while mutably borrowing `self`; as per the very first line in its docs:

> Consumes the `Box`

You either need to `.clone()` it or use a function that consumes `self` (e.g. `fn open(self)`).

I recommend re-reading [The Rust Book's chapter on Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/ownership.html).